# Remove nested html before jquery.tablesorter parser starts working?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm having several parsers and in one column is a problem because it contains hidden content (mouseover box). To avoid this problem I want to remove the complete content that is nested.

f.e.:

```
<td>50,3<span>12 payments</span></td>
<td>20,1<span>230 payments</span></td>
```

My parser converts the german formatted number into float:

```
    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: "floatval",
        is: function(s) {
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s) {
            return s.replace(/\./g,"").replace(/,/g,".").replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, "");
        },
        type: "numeric"
    });
```

But in this special column I need to remove nested html as well. At the moment I used a special parser that does both, but I thought if there is a solution to change the string before it goes through the parser (the parser removes html tags so I loose the ability to remove nested html)?!

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. After two days I hopefully finished the filter.

Maybe its the best to replace the core tablesorter filters "percent", "currency" and "digit" against this powerful digit filter:

```
// return floating point number (handles 1.- or 1.--)
s = parseFloat(
    // remove whitespace 1 234,56 and quote 1'234,56 followed by three digits
    s.replace(/[' ](?=[0-9]{3})/g, '')
    // remove all html tags and linebreaks
    .replace(/(<.*?>|\s)/g, ' ')
    // remove anything after last digit of first number
    .replace(/([0-9])[^0-9-.,].*/, '$1')
    // replace commas by dots
    .replace(/,/g, '.')
    // remove anything except floating point
    .replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, '')
    // remove all dots except the last one
    .replace(/\.(?=.*?\.)/g, '')
);
```

Demo:

http://www.programmierer-forum.de/html/javascript-parse-float-extended.html

As you can see, it works with all international number formats (us, de, ch, etc.) and types (currency, percent, integer, float, etc.) and deletes all nested html tags plus it ignores all numbers following by the first one.

Feel free to enhance it (f.e. combining the last two replaces).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `textExtraction` instead ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/8cg4f/11/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    textExtraction: function(node){
        return node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
});
```

What that does is grab the value of the very first node (text node in this case), so you can't wrap the text in a span (or whatever) or this function won't work properly.

Comment: This doesn't work as some columns have nested values and some not. f.e. `<td>12.1</td>` and the other is `<td><span onclick="do_something()">strong</span><span class="hidden">details</span></td>`. Is it possible to define the textExtraction for a specific column?

Comment: Actually, you can't in the original version of tablesorter. But I've forked a copy of the plugin and I have made a bunch of enhancements including defining the textExtraction for each column - check out [a demo here](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html).

Comment: looks good. wait a little bit. I will suggest a new filter for numbers  within a short time. it removes nested tags and is able to read all number formats (us, de, fr, ch, etc.).

Comment: new filter added as answer :)